# Pandas dataframe subract values from two columns in same dataframe based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with columns `name`,`a`,`b`. If column `b` has -ve value subract it from column `a`. Only subract the value from column `a` if column `b` has -ve value.

```py
df
        name        a       b
0       anthony    10       5
1       marcus     75      -50
2       paul      100      -100
3       Aaron     200       7
```

Expected result:

```py
        name        a       b
0       anthony    10       5
1       marcus     25       0
2       paul        0       0
3       Aaron     200       7
```

Sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = '''\
name,a,b
anthony,10,5
marcus,75,-50
paul,100,-100
Aaron,200,7
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask for it:

```
df.loc[df['b'] < 0, 'a'] = df['a'] + df['b']
df.loc[df['b'] < 0, 'b'] = 0
```

It gives as expected:

```
      name    a  b
0  anthony   10  5
1   marcus   25  0
2     paul    0  0
3    Aaron  200  7
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use `df.clip`

```
df['a'] = df.a + df.b.clip(upper=0)
df['b'] =  df.b.clip(lower=0)

Out[11]:
      name    a  b
0  anthony   10  5
1   marcus   25  0
2     paul    0  0
3    Aaron  200  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but take out the column you're interested in as a series, perform any filtering on it then add it to the dataframe

```
s = df['b']
s[s > 0] = 0
df['a'] = df['a']  + s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean mask:

```py
b_neg = (df['b']<0)
df['a'] = df['a'] + b_neg * df['b']
df['b'] = (1-b_neg) * df['b']

df
      name    a  b
0  anthony   10  5
1   marcus   25  0
2     paul    0  0
3    Aaron  200  7
```